# Web Part Error Message

Tags: 2013, web-part, error

I have a team site in SharePoint 2013.  When I go to the home page the following error message appears:

> Could not load file or assembly 'LightningConductorWebPart, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=78ce3a8925a5972f' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

When I go to SharePoint designer the error message tells me to go to the Web Part Maintenance page and delete the LightningConductorWebPart.

However, when I open the web part maintenance page there isn't a LightningConductorWebPart listed. Instead the following web parts are listed: Content Editor, RSS Feed, Summary Link Web Part, Error Web Part, and Content Editor Web Part.

Has anyone seen this error before and what I can I do to delete the Web Part to see the home page without the error page?

Is there another web part that could be producing the error message?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Please try deleting "Error Web Part" from web part maintenance page. This is your "LightningConductorWebPart" which is throwing error.

Comment: Thank you, Amit.  I deleted the "Error Web Part", however, when I navigate back to the home page the error message still appears.  Is there something I can within designer?

Comment: Did you check-in the page? Can you please look into SharePoint ULS logs for the error. Since you have removed the Webpart which was throwing error, it shouldn't be there.